# pdoTools -> pdoMenu ModX Revo - hereClass

Tags: cms, modx, menu, revo

Добрый вечер. Пару часов повозился и так и не смог прийти к ответу. На странице есть основное меню реализованное также через pdoMenu. А на странице услуг сами пункты меню работают и переходят на нужную ссылку, но active не туглится при переходе:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
[[pdoMenu?
                    &hereClass=`service_desc-cat_active`
                    &tpl=`@INLINE <li class="service_desc-cat"><a href="[[+link]]" [[+attributes]]>[[+menutitle]]</a>[[+wrapper]]</li>`
                    &parents=`5`
                    &level=`0`
                ]]
                <!-- <ul>
                    <li id="srvice_desc-cat-1" class="service_desc-cat service_desc-cat_active">
                        <p>Эвакуация мотоциклов</p>
                    </li>
                    <li id="srvice_desc-cat-2" class="service_desc-cat">
                        <p>Эвакуация легкового авто</p>
                    </li>
                    <li id="srvice_desc-cat-3" class="service_desc-cat">
                        <p>Эвакуация внедорожников <br />и минивенов</p>
                    </li>
                    <li id="srvice_desc-cat-4" class="service_desc-cat">
                        <p>Прикурить ваше авто</p>
                    </li>
                    <li id="srvice_desc-cat-5" class="service_desc-cat">
                        <p>Трезвый водитель</p>
                    </li>
                    <li id="srvice_desc-cat-6" class="service_desc-cat">
                        <p>Эвакуация спецтехники</p>
                    </li>
                </ul> -->
```

Так выглядит сейчас код.
Отображается следующим образом:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А должно вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Классы все прописаны правильно.
Вот иерархия ресурсов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Буду очень благодарен, если разъясните в чем проблема.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Свойства для CSS классов такие как: `&firstClass`, `&lastClass`, `&hereClass` и т.д. добавляются в плейсхолдеры `[[+classes]]` и `[[+classnames]]` `([[+classes]] = class="[[+classnames]]")`

Поэтому Вам надо добавить этот плейсхолдер:

```
&tpl=`@INLINE <li class="service_desc-cat [[+classnames]]"> ...
```

P.S. И не забудьте отключать кеширование

```
[[!pdoMenu? ........ ]]
```

Comment: О даа. Спасибо !)